# Google Query Function - Wrong Value

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I cannot pull correct data using "GOOGLE Query" please advise how I can resolve it.
I am getting wrong value instead.

Link to Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/.../1D.../edit...

Query =QUERY(A1:F5,"SELECT D WHERE D='D167' and C='C168'",1)

Please refer to Green Cell

The answer I am getting is " Analyst" which is in D1

The answer I am expecting is "30" which is in D2

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Comment: Hey couldnt access the sheet. Maybe you can share a picture of your before and desired outcome. Also your source data. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change how these references are, but if D167 is a number, use `"&D167&"`, but if its text, use `'"&D167&"'`. If you were looking up 'Analyst' in D, you'd use `'"&D167&"'`

As it sits right now, your QUERY is looking for the literal values of D167 and C168 and not the cell references.

```
=QUERY(
  A1:F5,
  "SELECT D 
   WHERE 
    D="&D167&" and 
    C='"&C168&"'",1)
```